# gdb debugging in Terminal OS X (10.8.5) with zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, gdb, zsh, oh-my-zsh

For my studies I have to run a binary unix-program `bomb` with gdb. 
Some time ago I followed the steps on http://jakoblaegdsmand.com/blog/2013/04/how-to-get-an-awesome-looking-terminal-on-mac-os-x/ and made some changes to my terminal-setup.
To run`bomb` with gdb I typed:

```
 -> bomb207  gdb bomb           
zsh: correct 'gdb' to 'gdv' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: gdb
```

When I type 'man gdb' zsh answers 'No manual entry for gdb'
How can I change my terminal-setup to support gdb?

ps. 
I already installed the command line tools for os x with x code and I didn't had any problems until now...
bomb207 is the current directory and the location of `bomb`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that Apple (who have been switching from `gcc` to `clang` for some time) stopped including `gdb` in 10.8. Even in the CommandLine tools.

The clang debugger is [`lldb`](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html). It [is similar in use to `gdb`](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html), and I'm not finding it unduly difficult to switch. Aside from explaining to my finger that they shouldn't type `gdb`
 for the debugger anymore: my fingers don't like change.

---

Yes, you can still type `gcc` to compile things, but look:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 2):

on 10.15.6+ you can simply install gdb using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install gdb
```

Comment: I cannot install it... 

MacBook-Air TestFolder % brew install gdb
gdb: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.
Error: gdb: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install GNU Debugger, or GDB. Try installing the full XCode package?

GDB works fine on my Mac, but then I've got full XCode installed.

Failing that, just for my peace of mind, type 'where gdb' and tell me what it prints out?

On my Mac it's in '/usr/bin/gdb', and on my linux boxes it's in '/usr/bin/gdb' and '/usr/bin/X11/gdb'.

Comment: it prints 'gdb not found'